# I am using Windows 10 and trying to install BizTalk server 2016 62bit but i am getting this error

Tags: server, installation, single-sign-on, biztalk, biztalk-2016

> The following platform component failed to install and will need to be manually installed before setup can proceed: enterprise single sign-on server: unspecified error BizTalk 2016 installation error in windows 10

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect that this is not the correct place to ask this question.
You might have better luck in superuser.com or in serverfault.com. This site is more about writing code and less about installing software.

Comment: Windows 10 comes in various versions,   some of the lower version such as Home won't support SSO.  There are also other limitation such as "SMTP Server is not available on client operating systems, such as Windows 8.1 or Windows 10." when it comes to IIS.  You would be better off doing it on Windows Server 2016
or Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Too little information to solve this puzzle.  Check out the installation prerequisites and make sure your version of Windows 10, software and hardware configuration will support BizTalk 2016.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-biztalk-server-2016